# complex Mysql query for chat with Sort by desc leaving NULL on last

Tags: mysql, null, chat

I have two tables sms_contacts and  sms_twoway_chat. Contact table use id as PK and contact_type is used for 3 psooible types of contacts (0,1 and 2)
sms_twoway_chat holds all chats between two contacts.

I need all contacts with contact_type 0, either they have chat or not
I need only contacts with contact_type 1 and 2 who has received replies
I need unread  (is_read = 0) and recent response of chat (date_time desc ) on top

What I have done is showing Null on top, like contact of type 0 who don't have any record in chat table are displaying on top, whereas they should be on last

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sms_contacts` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `contacts_name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `contacts_phone` varchar(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_time` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `date_time_unix` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `contact_type` int(1) DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '0=>contact 1=>group , 2=>instant msg',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=19 ;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sms_twoway_chat` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `inbound_id` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sender_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `receiver_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_read` int(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `msg_body` text,
  `date_time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `date_time_unix` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=89 ;
```

This is what I have tried

```
SELECT a.*
  FROM ( SELECT c.id,c.`contacts_name` FROM sms_contacts c
LEFT JOIN sms_twoway_chat tc ON c.id = tc.`receiver_id`
WHERE user_id = 1 AND c.contact_type = 0
ORDER BY -tc.`is_read`,  tc.date_time DESC
       ) a
 UNION
SELECT b.*
  FROM ( SELECT c.id,c.`contacts_name` FROM sms_contacts c
INNER JOIN sms_twoway_chat tc  ON c.id = tc.`receiver_id`
WHERE user_id = 1 AND c.contact_type IN(1,2)
ORDER BY -tc.`is_read`,tc.date_time DESC
       ) b;
```

> **What about this as a solution ??**

```
SELECT *
    FROM (
        SELECT c.id AS i,  1 AS dt
        FROM sms_contacts c 
        WHERE user_id = 1 AND c.contact_type = 0
    ) t1 
LEFT  JOIN 
(SELECT *
    FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT sender_id AS i, MAX(date_time) AS dt
        FROM sms_twoway_chat 
        WHERE `inbound_id` <> "" AND `receiver_id` =1
        GROUP BY sender_id 
        ORDER BY MAX(date_time) DESC, sender_id
    )t3 )t2
ON t1.i = t2.i
ORDER BY t2.dt DESC
```

Comment: Why would a nullable column have a default value?

Comment: It might help that inbound_id with blank value in sms_twoway_chat table means it a message sent and filled value means its a response

Comment: Please edit to show the desired result

Answer (score 0):

This might help someone

```
SELECT *
    FROM (
        SELECT c.id AS i,  1 AS dt, c.`contacts_name`
        FROM sms_contacts c
        WHERE user_id = 1 AND c.contact_type = 0
    ) t1
LEFT  JOIN
(SELECT *
    FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT sender_id AS i, MAX(date_time) AS dt, 2 AS contacts_name

        FROM sms_twoway_chat
        WHERE `inbound_id` <> "" AND `receiver_id` =1
        GROUP BY sender_id
        ORDER BY MAX(date_time) DESC, sender_id
    )t3 )t2
ON t1.i = t2.i
ORDER BY t2.dt DESC LIMIT 0,100
```